# Select specific columns from CSV to graph with HighChart in a loop

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, highcharts

Currently my code successfully produces the charts I want from the addresses of the multiple csv files that are in the csv_files_addresses array.

However in each of these charts there are many elements which makes them hard to read accurately. I wanted to groups similar elements in their own separate charts. I have an input called "columns" which is an array that looks like this:

```
columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'break', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 'break', 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 'break', 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 'break', 26, 32, 33, 34, 'break']
```

So for example, for each of the csv files I would like the first chart to only have columns 1-6 included for all rows, in the next chart columns 7-14 for all rows and etc.

I would hope this loop would be within the already created loop (the one that creates a chart for each csv file in csv_files_addresses)

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var no_of_csv_files = csv_files_addresses.length;

      //For each csv file produce a Highcharts graph
      for (var i = 0; i < no_of_csv_files; i++) {
          data = (csv_files_addresses[i]);

          $.each(csv_files_addresses, function (i, data) {
            $.get(data, function(csv) {

              $('#container' + i).highcharts({
                chart: {
                  zoomType: 'x',
                  type: 'column',
                },
                data: {
                  csv: csv,
                  lineDelimiter: "\n"
                },
                title: {
                      text: 'Charts'
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      title: {
                          text: 'Seconds'
                      }
                  },

              });

            });
          });
      $('#all_containers').append('<div id="container'+ i +'"style="width:75%; height:1000px;"></div>')
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at `startColumn` and `endColumn` in the API docs? See explanation here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data

Comment: @wergeld If I try create a loop for startColumn and endColumn it seems to produce the correct number of charts, but they are all duplicates. They all use columns 26-34 in every chart not 1-6 for the first chart, 7-14 for the second, etc. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing your new code I cannot say for sure but it appears that your loop is not in scope of what you want to loop through.

Comment: @wergeld I input the start and end column numbers as two separate arrays.
e.g start_columns = [1,7,15,25,32] 
In the above code  after " $.each(csv_files_addresses, function (i, data) { “
I have created another $.each function

"$.each({{start_columns}}, function (j) {"

and I also changed the container from “container + i"  to “container+i+j” in the highchair function and when appending to “#all_containers"

Comment: Could you update code in the questions with your code? It is easier to read then. Just a guess, but sounds like a problem with variables `i` and `j`.